# set Tw Cen MT typeface

Tags: fonts

I would like to set the Tw Cen MT font in my .tex document and have to run it using pdflatexmk since I'm using the `package{ocgx}`. Here is the base of my .tex file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\begin{document}
\setromanfont{Tw Cen MT}
test...
\end{document}
```

I tried different packages but it didn’t work and gave the error:

```
Undefined control sequence \setromanfont {Tw Cen MT}
```

How could I achieve it?

Comment: What is `Tw Cent MT`font? Can you enlighten us? Are you sure the font is available for pdflatex?

Comment: It is a sans serif type face (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twentieth_Century_(typeface).

Comment: If you want to use a font installed in your operating system you should use xetex or luatex not pdftex, but "didn't work" isn't helpful, please show the exact error message, and a small test document that produces the error.

Comment: Well, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX will be able to use the font out of the box. You will have to  amend your document a little bit.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have the font installed in your system font path then

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tw Cen MT}
\begin{document}

test...
\end{document}
```